# How do I exclude folder from 'find', but still browse in the Project view, in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Any way to do this? Cause it keeps indexing and searching through my log folders, and i want to exclude the folder from find, but be able to browse and look at the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it's not possible. Exclude works globally. There is a [related feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-23537), feel free to star/vote.